# Buffer constructor not treating encoding correctly for buffer length

Tags: node.js

I am trying to construct a utf16le string from a javascript string as a new buffer object.

It appears that setting a new Buffer('xxxxxxxxxx', utf16le) will actually have a length of 1/2 what it is expected to have. Such as we will only see 5 x's in the console logs.

```
var test = new Buffer('xxxxxxxxxx','utf16le');
for (var i=0;i<test.length;i++) {
        console.log(i+':'+String.fromCharCode(test[i]));
}
```

Node version is v0.8.6

Comment: I have managed to do a temp fix like so.


`var toSearch = new Buffer(query.string, query.encoding);
// Temp fix to the issue of encoding not handling propperly
if (query.encoding=='utf16le') {
 toSearch = new Buffer(query.string.length*2);
toSearch.write(query.string,0,query.string.length*2,query.encoding);
    }`

And have also submited this as an issue here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6240

Just incase it is a problem as it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

It is really unclear what you want to accomplish here. Your statement can mean (at least) 2 things:

1. How to convert an JS-String into a UTF-16-LE Byte-Array
2. How to convert a Byte-Array containing a UTF-16-LE String into a JS-String

What you are doing in your code sample is decoding a Byte-Array in a string represented as UTF-16-LE to a UTF-8 string and storing that as a buffer. Until you actually state what you want to accomplish, you have 0 chance of getting a coherent answer.

`new Buffer('FF', 'hex')` will yield a buffer of length 1 with all bits of the octet set. Which is likely the opposite of what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks,
JS-String to UTF-16-LE which I thought the encoding would handle? Or is there some converter required?

If it was treeting my javascript string as utf-16-le already wouldnt I end up with 10 bytes of x's with no 00 bytes inbetween? So it must do some sort of conversion?
It works the way I have written it apart from only being half the size that I am expecting.
The encoding would be UTF-16-LE and this is shown by the 00 bytes in between each x in the console log however we only see 5 x's.